# Why is the homework policy hard to find in the help pages?

Tags: feature-request

Has anyone else noticed it is hard to find the Biology SE help page which refers to homework questions? [Go to the help centre and search for 'homework'](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=homework) and it will not show up - I think this should be easier to find within the Biology SE help centre because there is a lot of homework q's coming up at the moment that do not meet the standards of the homework policy.

Could we make that help page easier to find?

Is it also possible to set it up so that tagging a question as homework automatically gives a pop-up telling the user to read the homework question policy?

Comment: There is no homework page in the help center. Do you mean we should convert the old meta post on homework into a help center page?

Comment: @MadScientist perhaps it would be good - I think a lot of new users are unaware of the meta aspect of the SE model so wouldn't look there

Comment: Really good point. I've also noticed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The homework policy is now at `https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework`([link](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework)). It should also be indexed soon by the help center search.

I'll also change the close reason to refer to the new page, but that needs a second moderator to approve the change.

Comment: The close reason has now been updated